# Apache camel - Writing file to ftp failed

Tags: java, ftp, apache-servicemix, camel-ftp

Below is my simple file component consumer to ftp producer component route.

```
from("file://C://fileFolder")
.to("ftp://ftp01.test.com/myfolder/?username=user1234&password=pass1234&delay=5s&ignoreFileNotFoundOrPermissionError=true");
```

When I paste a simple text file I'm getting below exception saying *"writing failed"*.

```
2016-01-15 10:55:37,663 | WARN  | C://fileFolder// | RemoteFileProducer               | 117 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.14.1 | Writing file failed with: Error writing file [KURUMDANBANKAYA/F2090281225.txt]
2016-01-15 10:55:37,712 | INFO  | C://fileFolder// | Tracer                           | 117 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.14.1 | ID-ESB01-55798-1452524440559-1-46 >>> (route21) ftp://ftp01.test.com.tr/KURUMDANBANKAYA/?delay=5s&ignoreFileNotFoundOrPermissionError=true&password=xxxxxx&username=garhdisigorta --> OnException[GenericFileOperationFailedException] <<< Pattern:InOnly, Headers:{CamelFileLastModified=1452848134261, CamelFileRelativePath=F2090281225.txt, CamelFileName=F2090281225.txt, CamelFileLength=486, CamelFileNameConsumed=F2090281225.txt, CamelFileNameOnly=F2090281225.txt, CamelFileAbsolutePath=C:\\fileFolder\F2090281225.txt, CamelFilePath=C:\\fileFolder\F2090281225.txt, CamelFileAbsolute=true, CamelFileParent=C:\\fileFolder}, BodyType:org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFile, Body:[Body is file based: GenericFile[C:\\fileFolder\F2090281225.txt]]
2016-01-15 10:55:37,712 | INFO  | C://fileFolder// | Tracer                           | 117 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.14.1 | ID-ESB01-55798-1452524440559-1-46 >>> OnException[GenericFileOperationFailedException] --> direct-vm://nip-dead-letter-channel <<< Pattern:InOnly, Headers:{CamelFileLastModified=1452848134261, CamelFileRelativePath=F2090281225.txt, CamelFileName=F2090281225.txt, CamelFileLength=486, CamelFileNameConsumed=F2090281225.txt, CamelFileNameOnly=F2090281225.txt, CamelFileAbsolutePath=C:\Target\fileFolder\F2090281225.txt, CamelFilePath=C:\Target\fileFolder\F2090281225.txt, CamelFileAbsolute=true, CamelFileParent=C:\Target\fileFolder}, BodyType:org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFile, Body:[Body is file based: GenericFile[C:\Target\fileFolder\F2090281225.txt]]
2016-01-15 10:55:37,712 | ERROR | C://fileFolder// | FatalFallbackErrorHandler        | 117 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.14.1 | Exception occurred while trying to handle previously thrown exception on exchangeId: ID-ESB01-55798-1452524440559-1-46 using: [Channel[sendTo(Endpoint[direct-vm://nip-dead-letter-channel])]]. The previous and the new exception will be logged in the following.
2016-01-15 10:55:37,712 | ERROR | C://fileFolder// | FatalFallbackErrorHandler        | 117 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.14.1 | \--> Previous exception on exchangeId: ID-ESB01-55798-1452524440559-1-46
org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Error writing file [myfolder/F2090281225.txt]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.writeFile(GenericFileProducer.java:279)[117:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.processExchange(GenericFileProducer.java:165)[117:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFileProducer.process(RemoteFileProducer.java:49)[237:org.apache.camel.camel-ftp:2.14.1]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)[117:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor$2.doInAsyncProducer(SendProcessor.java:152)[117:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(ProducerCache.java:304)[117:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:147)[117:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.1]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)[117:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:163)[117:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:416)[117:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)[117:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)[117:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)[117:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)[117:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:433)[117:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:211)[117:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:175)[117:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:187)[117:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:114)[117:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.14.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)[:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)[:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)[:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)[:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)[:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)[:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.7.0_75]
```

After googling and reading some camel related blogs, following are the trials and cases I tried

1. Checked network firewall - not blocking
2. Checked windows firewall - not blocking
3. Checked manual file transfer to ftp - worked
4. Checked java way of transfering file using commons-net-3.7.jar 
   FTPClient - working

Only through servicemix its not working. Writing file failed. Anyone has got the same issue solved?

Comment: Are you using a secured FTP, like SFTP oder FTPS? Does the FTP server log something specific?

Comment: Got full access to ftp. Provided username and password only are being used.  Its working fine (My File transfer route) in one of the server. In another server its throwing exception saying writing failed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to add `passiveMode=true` to the URI.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your camel route :

> from("file://C://fileFolder")
>   .to("ftp://ftp01.test.com/myfolder/?username=user1234&password=**pass1234delay**=5s&ignoreFileNotFoundOrPermissionError=true");